# Cannot use maven dependency in source code

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm having the following problem. I've added a new dependency on my project pom.XML then I execute 'mvn clean install' so the maven has downloaded this dependency successfully but still cannot use it in my source code. 
Look that External Libraries does not contain the dependency's jars.
What's the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: via intellij-idea settings, enable   Import maven projects automatically

Comment: @mustabelMo how can i do it manually without automation? I am learning maven and would like to know the processes. Or it's just intellij related staff ?

Comment: I checked in my IDE, perhaps the version you provided is wrong, I replaced it by this [one](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Getting-Started) and it worked,

Comment: @mustabelMo Ok I tried this version, but the problem is the same. Also by enabling Import maven projects automatically nothing has happened.

Comment: to process it manually, a `maven clean install` does the work. or click [this icone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5SCb.png)